# How to handle Azure web app versioning?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I am about to develop a new website (SaaS) project and want to use Azure as the platform. I want every clients data to be isolated from each other which i chose to achieve by using elastic database engine.

Each client must have a specific endpoint like bla.siteName.com, bla2.siteName.com, bla3.siteName.com this is easily achieved by subsomains and usage of custom domains.

And finally website itself should be hosted on azure web app but here is where i hit a wall.

I want to be able to move each client at a time to the newer version of the web application.

So if My web app is runing version 1.0, and i add a new feature in version 1.1, i want to be able to move client and clients db to version 1.1 without them noticing it.

So far my thought is to publish new web app version 1.1 and move subdomain name of that specific client to version 1.1 web app. But this will end up in downtime, because switch of subdomains take time.

Am i missing something or am i just about to overengineer something that is very simple?

Or should i just focus on single website serve all approach, and just upgrade all clients databases at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try [Azure Deployment Slots](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/05/16/deploy-app-azure-app-service/). It has many uses, including the one you describe. You can use Azure Traffic Routing to route a subset of your users to one of your deployment slots.

Comment: I see that I can have a new version in a separate deployment spot. But how  will deployment slot help me move a single customer at a time to new version?

Comment: @Timesen - Have you spent any time really digging into what deployment slots can do?

Comment: As I understand deployment slots can be swapped one with an other where each deployment slot is a website. So I don't get how can I use swap of deployment slots for my scenario of moving a single client to new version? If I swap then all clients will be moved

Comment: Take a look at Deployment Slots and Traffic Routing. TR allows you to route a subset of your users to one of your deployment slots.

Comment: @Timsen - Glad to be of assistance!

Comment: The link is down, i'd edit it but the queue is full, so for anyone looking, the current one seems to be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots